# Rading csv file contents in a structure array and display them on Console

Tags: c, csv, pointers, structure

I'm a noive programmer in C. I'm stuck a bit in reading csv file contents in a structure array and have some issues with pointers.

The cotents of mwecsv.csv file are

```
ID,DateWeek
Schd5,Monday
Schd3,Tuesday
```

My implementation is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct Sample
{
    char *id;
    char *day;
}Sample;


int main (){

    struct Sample sample[100];


    char buffer[1000];
    char *data;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("mwecsv.csv","r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("file exists and opened\n");

    //read the first line=> Header
    fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp);
    printf("%s\n",buffer);

    int counter = 0;
    while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp)){
        printf("***********\n%s\n******************\n",buffer);
        // parsing
        data = strtok(buffer,",");

        printf("first token is %s\n", data);
        printf("dataStr is %s\n", data);
        sample[counter].id = data;
        
        data = strtok(NULL,",");
        printf("second token is %s\n", data);
        sample[counter].day= data;
        counter++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

      for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        printf("%s %s\n",
                sample[i].id,
                sample[i].day);
      printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This program outputs:

```
file exists and opened
ID,DateWeek

***********
Schd5,Monday

******************
first token is Schd5
dataStr is Schd5
second token is Monday

***********
Schd3,Tuesday
******************
first token is Schd3
dataStr is Schd3
second token is Tuesday
Schd3 Tuesday
Schd3 Tuesday
```

The last two lines in the output should be:

```
Schd5 Monday
Schd3 Tuesday
```

I think it has something to do with the pointers in my code, but unfortunately, I can't figure it out. I tried using strcpy and memcpy but they did not solve the issue. Any hint would be helpful to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your struct contains pointers...

```c
struct Sample
{
    char *id;
    char *day;
}Sample;
```

Unrelated note... This is creating a global variable of type `struct Sample` named `Sample`.  This will work as you expect without the extra variable:

```c
struct Sample
{
    char *id;
    char *day;
};
```

In the loop where you are parsing, you are assigning different parts of the `buffer` to `sample[counter].id` and `sample[counter].day`.  When you do this:

```
data = strtok(buffer,",");
```

`data` will be pointing into `buffer`.  `strtok` isn't creating something new, it is editing `buffer` and giving you back a pointer to it.  So when you assign to your struct members:

```
sample[counter].id = data;
...
sample[counter].day= data;
```

You are assigning those pointers to an address inside buffer.  Please note that when you do this, C is not magically copying the contents of the buffer being pointed to.  It's just copying the address itself.  C isn't going to go behind your back and do anything for you.  That's one of its powers.  Very little in the way of implicit behavior = full control.

Then, on the next loop, this completely overwrites what is in `buffer`:

```
while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp))
```

At this point, your struct members are now incorrect from the previous loop.

There are 2 ways to handle this.  You can keep pointers in your struct and allocate space to those pointers that then get a copy of `data`, or you can make the struct contain buffers themselves.

#### Method 1: Keep the same struct, but allocate space to the pointers that can contain a duplicate.

This just changes the 2 lines where you set your struct members.

```c
sample[counter].id = strdup(data);
...
sample[counter].day= strdup(data);
```

Note that `strdup` is allocating *for you*, so that memory is on the heap.

#### Method 2: Change the struct layout to contain its own buffers

```c
struct Sample {
    char id[100];
    char day[25];
};
```

Then, change your struct member assignments like this:

```c
strcpy(sample[counter].id, data);
...
strcpy(sample[counter].day, data);
```

The goal of both of these approaches is to copy the data out of `buffer` before it gets overwritten on the next iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

### The program works as follows.

You define the buffer `char buffer[1000];`.

During the first iteration of the loop

```
while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp))
```

you read 12 characters "Schd5,Monday" into `buffer[0]` to `buffer[11]`; `buffer[12]` gets a value of zero or NULL (`\0`) (remember we work with null-terminated strings).

```
data = strtok(buffer,",");
sample[counter].id = data;
```

Function `strtok()` searches for a comma, finds it at `buffer[5]`,  overwrites it with a zero byte (`\0`) (see https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) and returns a pointer to `buffer[0]`, which is the beginning of the first "token". Now, `sample[0].id` points to `buffer[0]` and `buffer` containes `"Schd5\0Monday\0"`.

```
data = strtok(NULL,",");
sample[counter].day= data;
```

Now, `sample[0].day` points to `buffer[6]`, which is the beginning of the second "token".

```
fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp)
```

On the second iteration of the loop, you read the next line "Schd3,Tuesday" from the file into `buffer`. **The (old) value `"Schd5\0Monday\0"` gets overwritten at this moment.** After `strtok(...)`, the buffer contains `"Schd3\0Tuesday\0"`, however, `sample[0].id` still points to `buffer[0]` that now contains `"Schd3\0"` and `sample[0].day` still points to `buffer[6]` that now contains `"Tuesday\0"`.

`sample[1].id` and `sample[1].day` also point to `buffer[0]` and `buffer[6]` respectively, that is why you have the same output `Schd3 Tuesday`.

### Solution

You may either

- get some memory (like a 2-dimensional array) to contain the copies of the strings of your csv file (not pointers to the buffer that will be overwritten) and copy the strings there or
- allocate memory from the heap for every string of the text file (as soon you know the length) and copy the string there; don't forget to carefully free up this memory after use or
- "decode" the strings as you read it (for example if those are numbers or "decode" "Monday" to 1, "Tuesday" to 2 etc.) or
- use something like a "string" class if you are in C++.